# How to detect an Angular Universal prerender build?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I have an Angular 16 app that will select a random background image once when the app starts up, it works like this:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly backgroundImagesCount = 8;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.backgroundImagesCount + 1);
    this.document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('/assets/bg${randomNum}.jpg')`;
  }
}
```

I've just added Angular Universal to this app so it can prerender the routes. The problem is that the "random" background is now hard-coded into the prerendered HTML. When the app starts up you will briefly see the pre-selected "random" background flash, and then the actual angular app bootstraps and the real random background is selected.

How can I detect the prerendering in my application?  Ideally I'd like to just skip this BG image stuff when prerendering but allow it to run once the app bootstraps. is there something I can use that can work like this pseudo-code below?

```ts
if(!isPrerendering){
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.backgroundImagesCount + 1);
  this.document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('/assets/bg${randomNum}.jpg')`;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can skip executing this code using `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId` and checking whether it is server with `if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {.... skip setting BG image}`

Comment: That might just work! Thanks. Another possible option is that `this.document.defaultView?.navigator.userAgent` is an empty string when prerendering

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov That's absolutely the easiest way to do this, thank you. If you make an answer for that I will mark is as accepted.

Comment: You need to use the `TransferState` service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip executing some part of code by using `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId`

Check whether code is currently running on server side with `isPlatformServer()` method from @angular/common package.

`if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) { .... skip setting BG image }`